# regex capturing multiple group after a specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to capture all variable names after "define" keyword (im using js).

I already tried this:

```
(?<=define\s)(?:([a-zA-Z_]\w*),?\s?)+
```

but it only captures last occurrence, but i want to get all of them.
example string :

```
define x, y, z, a
```

link here [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GGfHEo/1)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a browser that [supports](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) an infinite quantifier in the lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<=define\s[\w,\s]*)[a-zA-Z_]\w*
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is at the left is

  - `define\s` Match define followed by a whitspace char
  - `[\w,\s]*` Match optional allowed chars in between
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `[a-zA-Z_]\w*` Match a single char a-zA-Z or _ and optional word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9pGHun/1)

```js
const s = "define x, y, z, a";
const regex = /(?<=define\s[\w,\s]*)[a-zA-Z_]\w*/g;
console.log(s.match(regex));
```

Comment: thank you, i wonder if is there anyway to do the same thing with capturing instead of matching ?

Comment: @outlandish No, not with JavaScript RegExp.

Comment: @outlandish The other way is to first match the format and capture the part that you want. Then after process the captured part to get the separate matches, as at that moment you know that you already have the right data. So that would be 2 regexps instead of 1, or a split and 1 regex etc..